# movement of image is not smooth while image is moving slow

Tags: javascript, css, html

I was trying to move an image to the left continuously (with a time delay) but I am unable to get the smoothness effect. I am getting jerky effect. I am using requestAnimationFrame inside the setTimeout as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
              background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/jei3ov2nl/moon_bg.png");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #poster {
                background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/582ctpzj5/gladiator.png");
                position: absolute;
                background-position:right 20px bottom 20px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 99999;
                background-color: transparent;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="poster"></div>

        <script>
            var poster = document.getElementById('poster');
            var animate;

            function moveLeft()
            {
                poster.style.left = poster.style.left || 0;
                poster.style.left = parseInt(poster.style.left) - 10 + 'px';
                setTimeout(function() {
                        requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
                        }, 50);
                //requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
            }

            moveLeft();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I change the interval to 10 in setTimeout() (or if I just use requestAnimationFrame instead of timeout), the movement is smooth but it is too fast and user can't see properly. Can anyone please let me know is there anyway to achieve the smooth effect with slow moving?

Below is the jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/un45c6s3/7/

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` inside a `setTimeout`? why?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/un45c6s3/8/

Comment: @JaromandaX: Excellent. Can you please post this as answer. I will accept it.

Comment: why on earth aren't you using a css transition for this instead of some whacky js?

Comment: @KaiQing - good point, but how do you learn how to do animation with JS unless you try?

Comment: @KaiQing: Whacky js? I need to change the image when one image is completely reached left. That is the reason I used Javascript to move the image instead of CSS

Comment: @kadina - you could use transition events to achieve the same - but I'm posting a JS solution anyway

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JaromandaX

Comment: But you can trigger the movements of images with JS by adding a class that transitions. your timeout is used to queue the swapping only and allow the browser to handle the movement. css transitions are given a duration, so you can easily set your timeout to match the transition length. In my opinion, using js to animate is valid in cases where you are moving spritesheets to replicate cell animation. I've done that and so much as I know there's no css answer for that kind of animation yet.

Comment: `you can easily set your timeout to match the transition length` - or use events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, this simple effect is better done using CSS transition, however, for the sake of learning:

Using `setTimeout` will always make things jerky, as `setTimeout` timing is not exactly consistent

The code below uses only `requestAnmationFrame`, and the speed is adjustable (specified in pixels per second)

Note: parseInt changed to parseFloat - because you can have fractional positioning of elements

```js
var poster = document.getElementById('poster');
var animate;
var previousMs = 0;
var speed = 100; // pixels per second
function moveLeft(ms) {
  if (previousMs !== 0) {
    var delta = ms - previousMs;
    // lets say we want to move 100px per second
    // we have d milliseconds, so speed*delta/1000;
    poster.style.left = poster.style.left || 0;
    poster.style.left = parseFloat(poster.style.left) - (speed * delta / 1000) + 'px';
  }
  previousMs = ms;
  requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
}
requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/jei3ov2nl/moon_bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#poster {
  background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/582ctpzj5/gladiator.png");
  position: absolute;
  background-position: right 20px bottom 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="poster"></div>
```

Now, you mention in the comment you want to do something when the animation is done

You can do so using CSS transitions and events

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  var poster = document.getElementById('poster');
  poster.classList.add('move');
  var done = function() {
   poster.classList.toggle('move');
  };
  poster.addEventListener('transitionend', done);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/jei3ov2nl/moon_bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#poster {
    background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/582ctpzj5/gladiator.png");
    position: absolute;
    background-position: right 20px bottom 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: transparent;
    left:0;
    transition:left 5s linear;
}
#poster.move {
    left:-100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="poster"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please help me to solve issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888917/image-is-not-moving-completely-to-the-left

Answer (score 1):

Why do it in javascript ? can you use CSS ?

the animations in CSS are amazing and are quite supported by the browsers, try it this way

> Click on image for animate.

```css
html, body {
 background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/jei3ov2nl/moon_bg.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
   }
   
#poster {
 background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/582ctpzj5/gladiator.png");
 position: absolute;
 background-position:right 20px bottom 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
 background-color: transparent;

        /* transition animation slow */
        transition: right 1000ms ease; 

        /* set init of animation */
        right:0%; 

   }
 .posterToLeft{
        right: 100% !important; 
        /* for example end of animation-transition */
      }
```

```html
 <div id="poster" onclick='this.className +=" posterToLeft";'></div>
```