# Image is not moving completely to the left

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to move the image completely to the left. But it is not moving to the complete left. I used ´requestAnimationFrame()´ as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-image: url("https://s14.postimg.cc/jei3ov2nl/moon_bg.png");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .animator {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="animator"></div>
        <script>

            function rollAnimate(element, url) {
                if(!element instanceof HTMLElement)
                    return;
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();
                var x = 0;
                var pattern;
                var framesPerSec = 10;

                img.onload = startDrawing;
                img.onerror = console.error;
                img.src = url;
                canvas.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;'

                function startDrawing() {
                    element.insertBefore(canvas, element.firstChild);
                    pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
                    resize();
                    anim();
                    window.addEventListener('resize', resize, {passive: true});
                }

                function anim() {
                    x = (x - 1) % img.width;
                    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,(canvas.height) - (img.height));
                    ctx.fill();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        requestAnimationFrame(anim);
                        }, 1000 / framesPerSec);
                }

                function resize(evt) {
                    canvas.width = element.offsetWidth;
                    canvas.height = element.offsetHeight;
                    ctx.fillStyle =  pattern;
                    ctx.rect(0, canvas.height - img.height, canvas.width, img.height);
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
                }
            }

            rollAnimate(document.querySelector('.animator'), 'https://s14.postimg.cc/tokio4ne9/mod_cropped.png');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Even though the image is moving to the left and repeating, it is not reaching left completely. Can anyone please let me know why the image is not reaching completely to the left.

Below is jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/1zu1bj5h/3/

Comment: well, don't you need to set a margin of 0 to the body to fix this? Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1zu1bj5h/12/ - padding:0; margin:0 for html,body ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `body { margin: 0; }` to remove the default margin of `body`

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyjb190h/1/